# WordPress - upload content direct to Database and use the template file

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using WordPress to create a website. I know how to create a template php file such as template.php for specific kinds of pages, and all these kinds of pages are going to use this template php file.

For example, I have 10 pages to be going to use this template php file such as template.php, but to some extent, I have to create 10 pages on the WordPress admin side to fill out the content for each page. In this case, it is hard to maintain in the future because what if I have 100 pages to use this template file? If I make some changes in the future, it is impossible to open and edit each page. So how can I upload the content to phpmyadmin database by some way like JSON or XML and retrieve the data and display them to the front-end?

I already took some time to google it but I did not find any answer for this.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Where to even start, you should `import` common assets like header.php or footer.php. Use `MySQLi` WordPress builtins or raw SQL to fetch data from your `MySQL` database. You can resort to using other drivers like `PDO`. When it comes to php class/file mgmt look into `PHP PSR-4` and auto-load using `composer`.